# Jquery Webcam on webpage help needed

Tags: jquery, webcam

Im trying to get webcam on my webpage.

my jquery code:

```
$("#camera").webcam({  
            width: 320,  
            height: 240,  
            mode: "callback",  
            swffile: "webcam/jscam.swf",  
    });
```

my body code for the webcam:

> `<div id="camera"></div>`

im using this plugin:
http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

but on my page i dont see anything. it's empty.
someone know what im missing to make the webcam work.

Thanks.

Comment: check your pages HTML source if you included the webcam js reference correctly or not and other required js references because as you shared your error ypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'webcam' it simply hints that there is no reference or no correct reference of webcam.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guess, but since you're using the callback mode did you try adding callback config like in the example ?

```
    onTick: function() {},
    onSave: function() {},
    onCapture: function() {},
    debug: function() {},
    onLoad: function() {}
```

Also do have any error? Did you check with firebug ?

---

1/ Ensure you loaded the JS lib.

2/ Try to put them in document.ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: i get the following error: webcam.html:18Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'webcam'

Comment: in save mode it also doesnt do anything

Comment: 1/ Did you import the js lib file ? 2/ You may try to put the `$("#webcam").webcam(...) call in a `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @Buit Then you should accept the answer if it helped you. The tick on the top left of the answer. Else people won't be enthusiast to give you more answers to your questions

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin from [here](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) if it doesn't help you, you can always join them to develop :)

Answer (score 0):

```
It might be throwing error in console please check it i.e jQuery is undefined.
So include js file in your html page.

eg:-

<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.webcam.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body>
<div id="camera"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#camera").webcam({
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    mode: "callback",
    swffile: "jscam_canvas_only.swf",
    onTick: function() {},
    onSave: function() {},
    onCapture: function() {},
    debug: function() {},
    onLoad: function() {}
});

});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try updating your web.xml file with the following :

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.swf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```